# extract all wanted words in a given string in C#

Tags: c#

How do I extract all the want words in a string and count them in C#?

here is the example

These are the words I want to extract: one, two, three

This is the given string: One times two plus one equals three.

The result should display one two one three and 4

Many thanks in advance

Comment: show us what u tried

Answer (score 1):

Its fairly easy. You can do it many ways, however i have chosen `split` and `Linq`

[String.Split Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance
>   that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode
>   character array.

[Enumerable.Select Method (IEnumerable, Func)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Projects each element of a sequence into a new form.

```
var myList = new List<string>
                  {
                     "one",
                     "two",
                     "three"
                  };

var input = "One times two plus one equals three";

var inputList = input.Split(new []{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(x => x.ToLower());

var result = inputList.Where(x => myList.Contains(x.ToLower()))
            .ToList();

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
Console.WriteLine(result.Count());
```

[**See the demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/O0RMEz)

**Updated for mjwills comoment**

> Would that match One?

To make sure its truly case sensitive

```
myList.Contains(x.ToLower())
```

**Update 2**

Or as mjwills pointed out again

> You could even consider using a case insensitive HashSet to make
>   Contains faster - removing the need for the ToLower

```
var set = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
         {
            "one",
            "two",
            "three"
         };
var input = "One times two plus one equals three";
var inputList = input.Split(new []{' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(x => x.ToLower());
var result = inputList.Where(x => set.Contains(x)).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
Console.WriteLine(result.Count());
```

Comment: @mjwills you are making me work for this one, just don't mention regex :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you want that what you ask but here is my Code :

```
public static int ExtractWordsOutOfString(this string s, List<string> filter)
        {
            int ret = 0;

            string[] s1 = s.Split(' ');

            foreach (string eachWord in s1)
            {
                foreach (string eachFilter in filter)
                {
                    if (eachWord == eachFilter)
                        ret++;
                }
            }


            return ret;
        }
```

and you can use it like :

```
string k = "one times two plus one equals three";

List<string> localfilter = new List<string>();
localfilter.Add("one");
localfilter.Add("two");
localfilter.Add("three");
localfilter.Add("four");

Console.WriteLine(k.ExtractWordsOutOfString(localfilter));
```